# C# Download Text to Speech from Google Translate comes with problems

Tags: c#, special-characters, google-text-to-speech

I'm trying to download a mp3 file generated by google translate and **although to achieve this**, the translation doesn't come as expected.

I'm portuguese and we use lots of special chars and I think that is the problem...

```
string text = "Teste de criação no ficheiro";
            string googleTextToSpeech = "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=pt&q=";
            string url = googleTextToSpeech + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(text);
            string url2 = googleTextToSpeech + text;

using (WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient())
            {
                myWebClient.DownloadFile(url, pathToSaveFile + "\\" + "mp3CriationTest.mp3");
                myWebClient.DownloadFile(url2, pathToSaveFile + "\\" + "mp3CriationTest2.mp3");
            }
```

The files are actually created but in both cases the voice says the same thing:
ok until "Teste de cria" (before 'ç' and '~') and ok with "no ficheiro". In the middle voice says something not very explicit...
Hope **I** was explicit. =)

As you can see I try with and without `UrlEncode` and same result... I try UrlEncode all url too.
I try it with `BinaryWriter`and the problem is equal.
I try it passing `new Uri(url)` in `myWebClient.DownloadFile` and nothing changes.

The thing that most annoys me is if you put the url result in your browser you can listen the right text to speech.
Try it:[http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=pt&q=Teste de criação no ficheiro](http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=pt&q=Teste%20de%20cria%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20no%20ficheiro)

"Teste de criação no ficheiro" stands for "File creation test".

Comment: It's probably because of wrong character encoding in the URL. Your example URL works in a browser. What do url and url2 look like?

Comment: I think WebClient.DownloadFile are in English and change my special chars for the english correspondante ones. I check my `myWebClient.Encoding` but it comes with "iso-8859-1 : Western European (Windows)" the right one =(

Comment: I don't know more what to do. I hope can one can help me or give me a consistent and easy alternative. Thanks.

Comment: Like I asked yesterday, what do url and url2 look like?

Comment: @bzlm Ups, I'm put it wrong... I edit the code to be ok... `path = url`and `path2 = url2`it's a copy paste mistake because I have it in differente functions

Comment: I know that. Now show us url and url2. :) What the browser actually requests is `/translate_tts?tl=pt&q=Teste%20de%20cria%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20no%20ficheiro`, which is the portuguese text encoded in UTF-8 and URL encoded to ASCII. I'm guessing this *isn't* what your web client is requesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works fine for me:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var text = "Teste de criação no ficheiro";
        var url = "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=pt&q=";
        url += HttpUtility.UrlEncode(text, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1";
            client.DownloadFile(url, "mp3CriationTest.mp3");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the `client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1";` do the magic! Thank you very much!